# skip function arguments javascript

Tags: javascript

For example I have this function

```
function example(a=1,b=1,c=1,d=1,f=1) {
 return (a*b*c*d*f)
}
```

So I have simple function with parameter which have default value.
And now when I call the function if I want to multiply a with `f`. I need to do that this way:

```
example(3,1,1,1,5)
```

Why I can't simply write first and last argument? Is that possible, something like:

```
example(3[1],5[5])
```

where numbers `[1]` and `[5]` determine the index of argument?

Comment: Why do you use so many underscores?

Comment: `where numbers [1] and [5] determine the index of argument?` because you are using javascript, not some language you made up to suit your immediate needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why I can't simply write first and last argument...

Because that isn't how function calls are defined in the JavaScript specification. That's the only reason.

I would suggest passing an object whenever you are not sure about the number of argument you are going to pass to a function.

If I were in your place, I would have written it as follows in ES5 and earlier:

```js
function example(params) {
  var DEFAULT = 1
  var a = params.hasOwnProperty('a') ? params.a : DEFAULT;
  var b = params.hasOwnProperty('b') ? params.b : DEFAULT;
  var c = params.hasOwnProperty('c') ? params.c : DEFAULT;
  var d = params.hasOwnProperty('d') ? params.d : DEFAULT;
  var e = params.hasOwnProperty('e') ? params.e : DEFAULT;

  return (a * b * c * d * e);
}

console.log(example({a: 3, b: 5}));
```

In ES2015 and above (you're using default arguments, so I assume you're happy with ES2015 features), you can do the above more cleanly using a combination of default arguments and destructuring:

```js
// This snippet requires that your browser support ES2015's default arguments and destructuring
function example({a=1,b=1,c=1,d=1,f=1}={}) {
  // Note -------^-------------------^^^^
  return (a*b*c*d*f);
}
console.log(example({a:3,f:5}));
```

There, we define that the actual argument will be an object, rather than discrete arguments, but we *receive* that object's properties as discrete arguments. We define that each property in the object has a default, and that the object iself is also optional (the `={}` at the end). (You can leave off the `={}` if you don't want to make `example()` a valid call.)

Answer (score -1):

No, you cannot directly reference function arguments using indexes as you described (example(3[1], 5[5])). In JavaScript, function arguments are accessed by their position or parameter names, not by indexes.

If you want to specify the values for specific parameters while keeping the default values for the other parameters, you can use an object as the argument and provide the specific parameter values using property assignments.

```
function example({ a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, d = 1, f = 1 }) {
  return a * b * c * d * f;
}

console.log(example({ a: 3, f: 5 }));
```

In this example, we're using an object {} as the argument and assigning specific values to the a and f parameters. The other parameters will take their default values. This way, you can achieve the desired behavior without explicitly providing values for all the parameters.

The output of the above code will be 15 since 3 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 5 equals 15.